# How to increment MAXIMUM value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to increment the revision no. (known as quot_rev, not a primary key as there is already record id) which is based on `quot_id`, so I need to get the maximum (highest) `quot_rev` value and then increment it when the user goes to the edit page, in which the user can save it as a new record.

```
    public function edit($quot_id)
    {$quotation = Quotation::where('quot_id', $quot_id)->orderBy('quot_rev', 'desc')->latest()->first();

    if ($quotation->quot_rev > 0){
        $quotation->max('quot_rev')+1;  
         }
return view('quotation.quotation_edit', compact('quotation', 'quot_rev'));
```

For the above code, laravel only show the **max quot_rev no.** but it didn't add 1 for me.

I have tried several ways like `$quotation->increment(max('quot_rev'));` and `$quotation->max('quot_rev')++;` but it all didn't work. Either it says error or it did not add 1.

Can anyone be able to help? I'm still a beginner at laravel.  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to send quotation and quote_rev seperatly. you can get it from quotation objct

```
   public function edit($quot_id)
        {
            $quotation = Quotation::where('quot_id', $quot_id)->orderBy('quot_rev', 'desc')->first(); // your query is duplicated, you can remove the latest(),

            if ($quotation->quot_rev > 0){
                $quotation->quot_rev  = $quotation->quot_rev+1;  
            }else{
                $quotation->quot_rev  = 1;
            }
            //if you want to save it in database as welll
            $quotation->save();

            return view('quotation.quotation_edit', compact('quotation'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public function edit($quot_id)
{
$quotation = Quotation::where('quot_id', $quot_id)->orderBy('quot_rev', 'desc')->first(); // your query is duplicated, you can remove the latest(),
$maximum = 0;
if ($quotation->quot_rev > 0){
   $maximum  = $quotation->quot_rev+1;  
     }
return view('quotation.quotation_edit', compact('maximum'));
```

If you just need the next quot_rev, you can just pass the $maximum variable

Hope this helps.